# Preview: How to set over-under configuration instead of side-by-side in "Two Pages" view?

Tags: macos, mac, pdf, preview

This question is about **Preview** (macOS builtin application). I am not asking for an alternative application, software of *hack* that "solves my problem". I know that there are plenty of ways of getting around this issue (eg not using Preview).

---

This is what you see when opening *landscape* documents on the *"Two Pages"* (`CMD+3`) view mode in Preview:

[image: sidebyside]

which is a very bad way of optimizing monitor space! Preview automaticaly puts pages side-by-side when the "Two Pages" view option is selected. This is perfect for *portrait* type documents. But for *landscape* type documents... not so much! Is there a way of *asking* Preview to render the pages in the over-under configuration, as oposed to the side-by-side configuration?

Example image of what I would like to see:

[image: overunder]